# Purge all PPAs with a single command

Tags: server, ppa, purge

How can I purge all added ppa with a single command in terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```